# How to search for C (language) tagged questions alone?

Tags: discussion, tags, search, fun

Hello All,

i tried to list out the questions that falls under C language. When i tried the search with "C", stackoverflow search option page is displayed. i tried "cprogramming","clanguage", "c programming","c language" but it doesn't give the expected result.

Expected Result : Displaying ONLY the questions that has C tags.

Quit funny :)

**EDIT:** But Certainly i know the workaround to get the list of C tagged question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use square brackets to specify the C tag: `[C]`

As in the URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[c]
```

Comment: Why the square brackets?  They aren't necessary, though they seem to do no harm.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: In a normal search the brackets signal a tag (http://stackoverflow.com/search) but I guess for `/questions/tagged/` search they're not required

Comment: Search terms that match the N most active tags are automatically converted to tag searches, so I don't know if this makes a difference...(I also don't recall how big N is. It was in the blog.)